# Insert non-text to Textbox.Text (WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf

I wont to insert `<StackPanel>` into `<TextBox.Text>` of the x:Name LabelTextBlock in order to add more features to the text.

### My code

```
<Color x:Key="Color.Control.Border.Focus">#164096</Color>

    <Duration x:Key="ColorDuration">0:0:0:0.5</Duration>
    <Duration x:Key="AnimationDuration">0:0:0:0.1</Duration>

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:AnimatedTextBox}">
        <Setter Property="AllowDrop" Value="true" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFF"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#222"/>
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
        <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        <Setter Property="KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation" Value="None"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.PanningMode" Value="VerticalFirst"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:AnimatedTextBox}">
                    <ControlTemplate.Resources />
                    <Border x:Name="Border"
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="0 0 0 2"
                            SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock x:Name="LabelTextBlock"
                                   Focusable="False"
                                   FontSize="{TemplateBinding LabelFontSize}"
                                   Margin="{TemplateBinding LabelMargin}"
                                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                   Foreground="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                   Text="{TemplateBinding Label}">
                                <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
                                    <TransformGroup>
                                        <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1"/>
                                        <TranslateTransform X="0" Y="-2"/>
                                    </TransformGroup>
                                </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
                            </TextBlock>
                            <Grid>
                                <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost"
                                              Focusable="false"
                                              HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                                              VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"/>

                                <TextBlock x:Name="HintTextBlock"
                                           Margin="5 0 0 0"
                                           Focusable="False"
                                           Foreground="{DynamicResource SolidColorBrush.Hint}"
                                           IsHitTestVisible="False"
                                           Opacity="0"
                                           Text="{TemplateBinding Hint}">
                                </TextBlock>
                            </Grid>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
                            <Trigger.EnterActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ColorAnimation Duration="{StaticResource ColorDuration}"
                                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush.Color"
                                                        To="{StaticResource Color.Control.Border.Focus}"/>
                                        <ColorAnimation Duration="{StaticResource ColorDuration}"
                                                        Storyboard.TargetName="LabelTextBlock"
                                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground.Color"
                                                        To="{StaticResource Color.Control.Border.Focus}"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </Trigger.EnterActions>
                            <Trigger.ExitActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ColorAnimation Duration="{StaticResource ColorDuration}" 
                                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush.Color"/>
                                        <ColorAnimation Duration="{StaticResource ColorDuration}"
                                                        Storyboard.TargetName="LabelTextBlock"
                                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground.Color"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </Trigger.ExitActions>
                        </Trigger>
                        <MultiDataTrigger>
                            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=Text.Length, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="0"/>
                                <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=IsFocused, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="false"/>
                            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <MultiDataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="{StaticResource AnimationDuration}"
                                                         Storyboard.TargetName="LabelTextBlock"
                                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)"
                                                         To="1"/>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="{StaticResource AnimationDuration}"
                                                         Storyboard.TargetName="LabelTextBlock"
                                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)"
                                                         To="1"/>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="{StaticResource AnimationDuration}"
                                                         Storyboard.TargetName="LabelTextBlock"
                                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[1].(TranslateTransform.Y)"
                                                         To="15"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </MultiDataTrigger.EnterActions>
                            <MultiDataTrigger.ExitActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="{StaticResource AnimationDuration}"
                                                         Storyboard.TargetName="LabelTextBlock"
                                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)"/>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="{StaticResource AnimationDuration}"
                                                         Storyboard.TargetName="LabelTextBlock"
                                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)"/>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="{StaticResource AnimationDuration}"
                                                         Storyboard.TargetName="LabelTextBlock"
                                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[1].(TranslateTransform.Y)"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </MultiDataTrigger.ExitActions>
                        </MultiDataTrigger>
                        <MultiDataTrigger>
                            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=Text.Length, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="0" />
                                <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=IsFocused, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="true" />
                            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <MultiDataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="{StaticResource AnimationDuration}"
                                                         Storyboard.TargetName="HintTextBlock"
                                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                                         To="1"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </MultiDataTrigger.EnterActions>
                            <MultiDataTrigger.ExitActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="{StaticResource AnimationDuration}"
                                                         Storyboard.TargetName="HintTextBlock"
                                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </MultiDataTrigger.ExitActions>
                        </MultiDataTrigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Comment: If you look into the documentation you will see that the Text property is type string. That should answer your question if it is possible to set a Stackpanel. You need an other container around your TextBox that does additional layout or maybe set the style of your textbox.

Comment: Yes, this I know, the question is how I change it from `string` to other property.

Comment: If you need an user input, create a usercontrol with `TextBox` and other content inside, if not, consider using `Label`, where you can put all to the content.

Comment: You can use a richtextbox if you need editing or a fixed/flowdocument if your purpose is display only. Editing seems to be mutually exclusive with a control you want to put a stackpanel inside. What sort of features are you thinking of?

Answer (score 0):

If you want a simple Image in your Textbox you could do something like this:

```xml
    <TextBox Text="Test 123" Padding="15,0,0,0" > <!--Adjust the Textstart after your Image-->
       <TextBox.Background>
          <ImageBrush ImageSource="pack://application:,,,/yourImagePath.png" AlignmentX="Left">
             <ImageBrush.Transform>
                <TransformGroup>
                   <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1"/> <!--Your Scaling here-->
                </TransformGroup>
             </ImageBrush.Transform>
          </ImageBrush>
       </TextBox.Background>
     </TextBox>
```

In case you want to do more complex things with your Textbox you have to create your own Textbox-UserControl. See [Creating UserControl](https://wpf-tutorial.com/usercontrols-and-customcontrols/creating-using-a-usercontrol/) for more details.

You cannot add other Controls to the Text-Property of the Textbox because it is of type string.